# Full Screen for youtube iframe not working when hosted on react-virtuoso on Android Webview

Tags: react-virtuoso

We have a site with youtube iframe video list (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). Only with this list component, switching to "full screen mode" not working good. It's entering to the full screen mode but exists from the mode immediately.

In order to Isolate the situation I did the following tests:

1. Chrome + react-virtuoso on android Works.
   **2. Android Webview + react-virtuoso - Doesn't work.**
2. Android Webview + Other list component - Works.

I assume it's related to the error: "Error: Zero-sized element, this should not happen"

Any ideas? How can I disable the above warning?